# WPF Diagramming Library

Tags: wpf, diagram

What free or open source WPF diagramming libraries have you used before? I'm working on my thesis and have no money to pay for the commercial alternatives.

Valid answers should support undo/redo, exporting to XML and hopefully good documentation.

I'm building an open source UML / database diagramming tool.

Answer (score 20):

sukram has a excellent series on CodeProject... it's a MUST READ!

- [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part2.aspx)
- [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part3.aspx)
- [Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

This is a nifty diagramming control for WPF:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SpiderControl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Diagram drawing you are looking for? 
WPF has great set of basic control [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx) which supports most mathematical drawing models like Spline Curve, Line, PolyLine, arc etc etc